# Why cakephp keeps old session data after re-login as another user id

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

On my system, some users manage multiple user IDs. I recommend users to logout before switching user ids but people accidentally re-login without logging out.
And it causes some hand-made session data for a user leaking to the others.

```
// On authorized top page action
public function index() {
    if (...) {
        $this->Session->write('mykey', 'You are user A');
    }
    echo $this->Session->read('mykey'); // user B could see 'You are user A'
}
```

I thought the following code fixes it but it breaks CSRF check on login form (guessing _Token key should not be deleted).

```
public function login() {
    $this->Session->destroy();
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Isn't the idea correct that core `AuthComponent::login` should always destroy the data except `_Token` key?
Or do I have to manually delete `mykey1`, `mykey2` .. before login? Or do I totally missing something?

- PHP 5.6.16
- CakePHP 2.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the auth component isn't supposed to clear any session data other than the user data, and even that data is not explicitly cleared, but overwritten. In case applicable, you could maybe invoke `$this->Auth->logout()` before trying to login, which will explicitly delete the user data (but of course will log out the user in any case, ie even if the new login attempt fails for whatever reason).

The only change the auth component applies to the session (besides writing to it), is that it renews it (in order to prevent session fixation attacks), ie it causes a new session id to be generated, and a new session cookie to be set.

### Remove the data manually

If you need to clear additional session data, then you need to do that on your own. Destroying the session surely is a little too destructive, instead explicitly delete the keys that you do not want to keep, ie:

```
$this->Session->delete('mykey');
```

If you want to remove everything but the `_Token` key, read the existing keys and delete all except that specific one, like:

```
$keys = array_diff(
    array_keys($this->Session->read()),
    array('_Token', /*'Config'*/)
);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $this->Session->delete($key);
}
```

Maybe you also want to sparse out `Config`, which contains session configuration/state information, not sure if removing it at a point where you still want to write to the session might have negative side effects. Also if you decide to remove the old data only after the new login was successful, you'll have to additionally sparse out `AuthComponent::$sessionKey`.

### Rely on user data being overwritten

In case it's all user specific data that you want to have removed, then writing it into the `AuthComponent::$sessionKey` key would be an option too, as that key is being overwritten by the auth component when logging in.

```
$this->Session->write(AuthComponent::$sessionKey . '.mykey', 'Your are user A');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it good idea to store the data into Auth.User.mykey namespace in the first place since the data is user specific rather than session specific. So It automatically descarded when logout or re-login.

Comment: Given that the data is being overwritten when logging in, that surely could be an option. I've updated my answer. @user3203239

Comment: Thanks again. I'm little hesitant to pollute core namespace but could be a good option and your answer is encouraging me a lot.

Comment: Note that I'm convinced that AuthComponent doesn't touch any user data because session data doesn't necessarily mean "Authorized Area Data" and they should be kept beyond the login form or so.